# Retrieve youtube playlist information from javascript?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I want to be able to load a youtube playlist ID, and retrieve all contained video ID's, kind of like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/tqWxc/1/
I see that it uses `$.getJSON`, which is jQuery.
I want to do this without jQuery.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more jQuery functions like `each` and `appendTo`. In plain JS -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqWxc/1407/)